# On which side is the root of this issue

Tags: callout

After callout with using a certificate, I receive the next msg in my dev console -
System.CalloutException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate

Could you pls specify from what side we have a problem - from the client-side (SF) or from server-side?

Do we need to add this certificate here?
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: What is the URL of the API you are calling?

Comment: @zaitsman Unfortunately your ip address needs to be whitelisted for callout 
Request has next structure

Comment: `
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setHeader('user', '1111111');
request.setMethod('GET');
Http requestClient = new Http();
request.setEndpoint('https://ppppp.compnename.us:8201/x/x');
request.setTimeout(60000);
request.setClientCertificateName('certname');
HttpResponse response = requestClient.send(request);
System.debug('response ' + response);
System.debug('response.getBody() ' + response.getBody());`

Comment: Try https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html and see if the certificate might be corrupted

Comment: Duplicate of https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/375265/jks-certificate-chain-in-call-out